# Simple qrcode to generate in DOMPDF

Tags: laravel, pdf, dom, qr-code, dompdf

Hi i cant generate simpleqrcode in dompdf

Here is my blade.php

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('svg')->size(200)->errorCorrection('H')->generate('string')) !!}">
```

in my controller

```
 public function printpdf($isbn)
    {
       $data = [
          'isbn' => $isbn
            ];

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('main.inventory.view_pdf ', $data);  
        return $pdf->stream($isbn.'.pdf');
    }
```

i tried this image and successfully render

```
<img src="{{ public_path('/uploads/image/1578635297.jpg')}}" style="width:30%;height:50%;">
```

Dont know why i cant generate qrcode to dompdf but when i generate in other blade its working but not in dompdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got mine working by initializing the `base64_encode(QrCode::format('svg')->size(200)->errorCorrection('H')->generate('string'))` in a variable within a controller, and passing it to the view.

Controller:

```
public function foobar() {
   $qrcode = base64_encode(QrCode::format('svg')->size(200)->errorCorrection('H')->generate('string'));
   $pdf = PDF::loadView('main.inventory.view_pdf', compact('qrcode'));
   return $pdf->stream();
}
```

View:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! $qrcode !!}">
```

Used **laravel-snappy** instead of laravel-dompdf. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

If you're still unable to generate a pdf file, then temporarily change the read-write permissions of the folder with `chmod -R 777 <folder_path>`.

Comment: Image not found or type i had try your code but not working dont know why. what laravel version are u using?

Comment: is it because dompdf not rendering png? ill try to render png image not working also.

Comment: Yes, I used simple qrcode and Laravel 5.8. I forgot to point out that I used [laravel-snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) instead of dompdf. Laravel-snappy is an alternative library to dompdf. It's also created by the same dev who made dompdf. Try using it and see if it works.

Comment: hi i install laravel-snappy dont know y this error appear "Failed to load PDF document".

Comment: Have you installed Wkhtmltopdf? Maybe you haven't published laravel-snappy's config file yet.

Comment: RuntimeException thrown with message "Unable to write in directory: /var/folders/5y/99pktykd2s39l41qpn77rhmc0000gn/T when i put download this error occured but when stream Failed to load PDF document" i already install Wkhtmltopdf nothing happen this is my config/snappy.php 'binary'  => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',

Comment: For the `$pdf->download()` error, try changing the read-write permissions of the folder temporarily with `chmod -R 777 <folder path>`. I got that similar error for download because of the permissions. For the `$pdf->stream()`, try returning just this `$pdf->stream()` and not this `$pdf->stream($isbn . '.pdf')`.

Comment: it works like a charm hi the problem is the permissions i feel so bad when i realized. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!

Comment: Use this instead to display QR Code in PDF file. <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64, {!! $qrcode !!}">

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me with php 8.1 in windows 10. Here is my code:

```
@php
    $qr = null;
    if (extension_loaded('imagick')) {
       $qr = QrCode::size(80)
                    ->format('png')
                    ->generate($my_qr_content);
    }
@endphp

@if ($qr)
     <img src="data:image/png;base64,{!! base64_encode($qr) !!}" />
@endif
```

Note that it works for both svg and png format.